# vbscript Get the line number after make ctrl+f in notepad

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, hp-uft, line-numbers

Well my question is: How can I get line number from notepad, I mean:
After make a "***ctrl+f*** " and find my text I want to know in which line number is it.

[image: screenshot]

Getting the text from ***status bar*** and store it in a string like "Ln 18, Col 1"

It is possible?
Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't necessarily care about Notepad, you want to loop over a text file and return the first position in which a string of text is found. Is this correct?

Comment: If you just want to detect the text in the text file, it'll be easier to use a `FileSystemObject`, open the text file for reading and find the data you want.  But if you specifically want to automate the use of Notepad, then you'll need to add the relevant objects to your OR and use `GetROProperty` to read the value after the "Find" action is complete

Comment: @JacobM. 
I use notepad because when I got a large file like a log, it takes a several minutes to search a string in the file, but when I make a "ctrl+f " it makes fastest, after I got the line number I need go to line number and take 10 lines forward from current line

And all thath in just two minutes or less

Comment: @Csanchez, What does using notepad and ctrl+f have to do with VBScript or with programming in general? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the question is about [tag:hp-uft] an automated testing tool.

Comment: @Motti ah thank you, I missed that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you spy on the status bar with UFT you'll see that it's identified as a `WinStatusBar` which has an **all items** property.

[image: Screenshot of spy]

This means that you can create an [output value](http://www.automationtutorial.com/qtpuft/uftqtp-output-values/) (in record mode). You can then parse the value and extract the line (and column) number.